# Linq-to-sql error: 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am having an error:

Error 2 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

This is my code:

```
public partial class mymymy : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int[] validType = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 13, 14, 16, 22 };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void LinqDataSource_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var dc = new soxMainDataContext())
        {
            var qry = from item in dc.LeaveRequests
                  where **validType**.Contains(item.Type)
                      && item.MgtApproval == null
                  select item;
            e.Result = qry;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What data type is the property item.Type ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I strongly suspect that `item.Type` isn't an `int`. Is it an enum? If so, try explicitly casting:

```
var qry = from item in dc.LeaveRequests
          where validType.Contains((int) item.Type)
                && item.MgtApproval == null
          select item;
```

Alternatively, as dot notation:

```
var query = dc.LeaveRequests.Where(item => validType.Contains((int) item.Type)
                                           && item.MgtApproval == null);
```

Comment: What if item.Type is an int? (Null able int )

Comment: @AvneeshSrivastava: Then it would depend on what type `validType` was, and what you'd want to do if `item.Type` is null. Assuming this is a problem you're currently facing, I suggest you try various things and then ask a new question with all the relevant details if necessary.

Comment: Hi Jon yes I am facing that issue I have asked a new question http://stackoverflow.com/q/37608704/2794391
I have also trying many things from morning please help me out.

Comment: and in case  item.Type is null-able int. use the  item.Type.Value

Answer (score 4):

`item.Type` isn't an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var consulta = from pr in lsprodcts 
               where pr.nProductoID.ToString().Contains(Idproducto.ToString())
               select new
               {
                   pr.nProductoID,
                   ProdName = pr.cNombre,
                   pr.cDescripcion,
               };
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to import Linq with `using System.Linq;` at the very top of the class.