# Entity Framework Contains Integer Array

Tags: .net, arrays, entity-framework, select, contains

```
public void GetMuscles(List<ListItem> selected)
 {
     int[] arrayOfStrings = new int[selected.Count];

     for (int i = 0; i < selected.Count; i++)
     {
         arrayOfStrings[i] = Convert.ToInt32(selected[i].Value);
     }  
}  

using (var db = new DWSEntities())
{
     var muscles = (from m in db.Muscles
         where m.MainMusleGroupID. //ISSUE
         select new { m.MusleName, m.ID }).Take(40);
}
```

In where statement I need to use contains but after "." I don't have option to use contains. I tried the same with a non integer value and it appears. I have an integer array and need WHERE IN clause. So is there any other way to do it without contains or how can I use contains with integer values?

Comment: I have tried that also but i get another error like "int[] does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension overload..."

Comment: Check that you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your .cs code file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Just I added (int) here:

```
m => arrayOfInts.Contains((int)m.MainMusleGroupID)
```

this is working code below:

```
var arrayOfInts = selected.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Value)).ToArray();
            using (var db = new DWSEntities())
            {
                var muscles = db.Muscles.Where(m => arrayOfInts.Contains((int)m.MainMusleGroupID))
                                        .Select(m => new { m.MusleName, m.ID }).Take(40);



                cblMusle.DataSource = muscles.ToList();
                cblMusle.DataTextField = "MusleName";
                cblMainMuscle.DataValueField = "ID";
                cblMusle.DataBind();
            }
```

Answer (score 10):

**My comment**

Sql `WHERE... IN` is inverted in Linq i.e.

```
 where MyIntArray.Contains(m.MainMusleGroupID)
```

or in lambda syntax

```
db.Muscles.Where(m => MyIntArray.Contains(m.MainMusleGroupID)
```

**Re : int[] does not contain a definition for 'Contains**

At the top of the class, ensure you have:

```
 using System.Linq;
```

*(and the below comment)*
Ensure that the type of the Entity field used in the `Contains` matches the type of the collection being compared to, i.e. `MainMusleGroupID` must itself be an integer, in order to be used with `arrayOfInts.Contains()`.

**Re : Refactoring**

The naming convention `arrayOfStrings` to indicate an array of integer (or actually, other numeric type, e.g. `long`) will cause maintainability issues.

You can simplify the creation of the `arrayOfX[]` array with LINQ: (note you have a extra `}` between the `for` loop and the `using`):

```
var arrayOfLongs = selected.Select(s => Convert.ToInt64(s.Value)).ToArray();
```

**Result**

```
var muscles = (from m in db.Muscles
    where arrayOfLongs.Contains(m.MainMusleGroupID)
    select new { m.MusleName, m.ID }).Take(40);
```

Or in Lambda syntax:

```
var musclesLambda = db.Muscles
    .Where(m => arrayOfLongs.Contains(m.MainMusleGroupID))
    .Select(m => new { m.MusleName, m.ID })
    .Take(40);
```

(I've changed the name of the array to match the type)

Comment: Same error "int[] does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension overload..." :( I think its just for string values. Cos it works if I use string values.

Comment: OK, I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1069106/314291) might be the issue - `MainMusleGroupID` probably isn't an `int` - possibly you've made some model changes (e.g. to `Enum`) or possibly its a `Guid`, Varchar, or other type. The type of `arrayOfStrings` will need to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: hmmmm, that can be... I will check and answer u again.

Comment: Unfortunatelly:( There is no problem in db and model. its integer value. I even recreated the model and still same error.

Comment: It worked with an extra '(int)'
m => arrayOfInts.Contains((int)m.MainMusleGroupID)

Comment: Which would I guess mean that `MainMusleGroupID` isn't integer :). I guess it will be something like `long`, in which case the better solution is to make `arrayOfStrings` a `long []`