# Nested Query in Linq with nullabe type comparison

Tags: c#, linq

Its look simple to me also (If I had to use SQL) but I have to do it with LINQ 
The Issue with this SQL Query.

```
Select  * from tbl_ClentBranch 
where client_ID in (Select clientID from tbl_Client where blah blah blah..)
```

I have gone through with lots of googling and find some solution but my scenario is bit different.

The `client_ID` is nullable, and I just want to ignore the record (of `tbl_ClentBranch` table) for comparison in where clause if `client_ID` contains null.

This is what I have done:

```
var clientID = _client.GetAll().Where(x => x.PortalID == PortalId)
                      .Select(x=>x.ClientID)
                      .ToList();
```

I am getting list of client but i am not able to use this client list to get clientbranch list 
Here `GetALL()` returns `IQueryable<Client>`

**Update:**

> ```
> var clientBranchList = _clientbranch.GetAll().Where(x => x.ClientID.Contains(clientID)).ToList();
> ```

Here I am getting issue when trying to get Clientbranch using clientID list

Here `GetALL()` returns `IQueryable<clientBranch>`

Comment: `_client.GetAll().Where(x => x.PortalID == PortalId && x.ClientID != null).Select(x=>x.ClientID).ToList();`

Comment: Did you try `Where(x => x.PortalID == PortalId) && x.client_ID.HasValue)`?

Comment: @SebastianSchulz HasValue is to be preffered over !=null

Comment: @Mafii Really? I prefer readable code. And if I use a ton of `==` and `!=` operators I prefer to use it for the rest of the statement too. The compiler replaces `!= null` with HasValue anyway. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676078/which-is-preferred-nullable-hasvalue-or-nullable-null

Comment: @Mafii Why is that?

Comment: @Nasreddine more readable. But if you read SebastianSchulzs comment you see that its just up to preference

Comment: Does the subquery always return 0 or 1 clientID or more?